# Cannot access foursquare API response, returning undefined?

Tags: foursquare

My request:

```
function getDataFromAPI(location, success) {
   var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/trending?";
   var settings = {
   ll: latlon,
   client_id: "*****ID******",
   client_secret: "******Secret*******",
   v: "20161208",
   callback: success
 };
 $.getJSON(url, settings, success);
}
```

This is returning the data to my console.  I can see it when I console.log(data) in:

```
function renderResults(data) {
   console.log(data);
   //NOT WORKING//
   //$(".area-results").append(data.response.venues);
   //NOT WORKING//
}
```

however, the response field is returned as "undefined".  Everything else in the code seems to be working, but I simply cannot access the response of trending places at the given location.  Even if I hard code lat and lon in, I cannot get the names to show up.

http://codepen.io/jawszone/pen/zoJMdZ

Comment: Solved: delete the "callback: success" in the request function.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the callback:success from your request function, because it is creating a second instance of the callback function that is different from the renderAPI function.